# Given a Parent Element, Testing for Certain Child Elements

Tags: jquery, html-table, parent, tablerow

I have the following code:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</table>
```

and

```
var $table = $('#myTable');
```

There is a condition in my JS where I will be appending table rows (`<tr>`) to this table, but I want to write a function to check to see if any have been added or not.

So I'm looking for a boolean expression that returns true if $table contains any `<tr>` tags, and false otherwise. Preliminary answers lead me to believe I need to use the jQuery ':has' selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (jQuery('table').find('tr').size() > 0) {
  // has element
}
```

Comment: Actually, this isn't quite right, in hindsight. Size is a function, and should have open/close parens after it. So:
`if (jQuery('table').find('tr').size() > 0) {`

Comment: Oh yeah, my mistake.  Thats a typo and would have been caught in the JS error console.  Updated with the fix.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the :has() selector. You can use any selector inside the parenthesis. For example, :has(tr) checks whether the element contains any tr elements.

Comment: @Matti, thanks for the quick response. Can you post an example of this?

Comment: The :has(tr) was the example. To elaborate, to check whether a certain jQuery object matches it, you can do myObject.is(":has(tr)"). To select any tables containing rows you'd do $("table:has(tr)"), and so on.

Comment: So it sounds like I'm going to use $("table").is(":has(tr)")? I need a boolean expression that returns true if a table has <tr> elements, and false otherwise... Thanks for your responses

Comment: @Mega Matt: just try it.  what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like :

```
jQuery("table").find("certainTr").size > 1
```

or [use the :has selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/has#selector)

I'm not 100% sure I understood your question... let me know if I'm off

Comment: @marcgg, I'm really just trying to check to see if a parent element has a certain tag under it. I think the :has selector is the right path. Are you able to post example code using this method?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('#myTable tr').length) {
//got some tr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you're trying to do is return true if your table contains any rows and false if your table contains no rows then you can try this...

```
return ($("#myTable tr").length > 0);
```

If you're going to have a header row though that is in the table at all times you might want to change the 0 to 1 in the above script.